# self._qs.unescape is not a function when using `gulp` with Twilio

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

Here is `global.js`:

```
var accountSid=     "MY_ACCOUNT_SID";
var authToken=      "MY_AUTH_TOKEN";
var twilioClient=   require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
twilioClient.messages.list(function(err, data) {
    data.messages.forEach(function(message) {
        console.log(message.body);
        console.log("======");
    });
});
```

When I open a command line, navigate to the directory of `global.js`, and run `gulp`, a web page opens. But when I check the console, I see this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: self._qs.unescape is not a function --- request.js:393`

What must I fix for the function to loop thru messages on my Twilio account and log them?

**Here are the contents of `gulpfile.js`:**

```
/*
  gulpfile.js
  ===========
  Rather than manage one giant configuration file responsible
  for creating multiple tasks, each task has been broken out into
  its own file in gulp/tasks. Any files in that directory get
  automatically required below.

  To add a new task, simply add a new task file that directory.
  gulp/tasks/default.js specifies the default set of tasks to run
  when you run `gulp`.
*/

var requireDir = require('require-dir');

// Require all tasks in gulp/tasks, including subfolders
requireDir('./gulp/tasks', { recurse: true });
```

The `./gulp/tasks` directory contains these `.js` files:

```
browserify.js
default.js
markup.js
publish.js
watchify.js
browserSync.js
dist.js
minifyCss.js
sass.js
watch.js
build.js
images.js
production.js
uglifyJs.js
```

**Contents of `./gulp/tasks/default.js`:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'images', 'markup', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a call to the Twilio API from the front end?

Comment: The code is on the node js back end code.

Comment: I just ran your exact code in the Node.js REPL and everything worked. What is gulp doing in this context? Why does it open a web page? Can you just run `node global.js`?

Comment: `node global.js` works fine. I am unsure how to check what `gulp` does exactly, as I am still new to it. But I'll try to paste some output

Comment: When you run `gulp` it will run the default task in your `Gulpfile` that's a good place to start looking.

Comment: @philnash updated the question with `gulpfile.js` contents

Comment: Ok, so I bet our default task is in default.js

Comment: @philnash Updated with contents of `./gulp/tasks/default.js`

Comment: OK, the default task seems to compile sass, do something with images, presumably compile some markup to HTML and then start the watch task, which I'm guessing watches some files for changes and reruns the compile tasks if they change. If you are getting an error at this point then it is probably to do with those tasks somehow. I'm not sure it has anything to do with your Twilio code. To run that code, have you tried just `node global.js` ?

Comment: @philnash Running `node global.js` prints the messages to the command line.

Comment: What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: @philnash That's what I expected it to do. When I run `nodejs global.js`, the program executes the `console.log()` commands to print messages to the console/command line. I was hoping it would be similar when running `gulp`

Comment: Ok, so we've discovered that running `gulp` does something with sass, images and markdown then probably watches those files for changes. So you should probably write a gulp function to run your global.js file and add it to that default task.

Comment: @philnash would i add `"global"` to the array that is the second argument of `gulp.task()`?

Comment: I'm no expert in gulp I'm afraid. I'd recommend reading a good intro to gulp which includes how to write a gulp task. This one might help: https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/